# Does injecting factory make sense in this scenario (Swinject)

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swinject

What is the right (cleanest and most concise) way to have `PetOwner` that can at any later point in program create new instances of `Cat`?

Let's assume that `createAnotherAnimal` can be called by `PetOwner` itself after it gets response to some async request, therefore creating as many instances of `Cat` as needed at the time of creating `PetOwner` is not possible.

I solved the problem with injecting factory, but I am not convinced that it is the best way to tackle the problem, what are the alternatives in Swinject?

```
protocol AnimalType {
    var name: String? { get set }
    func sound() -> String
}

class Cat: AnimalType {
    var name: String?

    init(name: String?) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func sound() -> String {
        return "Meow!"
    }
}

protocol PersonType {
    func play() -> String
    func createAnotherAnimal() -> Void
}

class PetOwner: PersonType {
    var pets: [AnimalType] = []
    let petFactory : AnimalFactory

    init(petFactory : AnimalFactory) {
        self.petFactory = petFactory
    }

    func createAnotherAnimal() {

        let pet = petFactory.factoryMethod()
        self.pets.append(pet)
    }

    func play() -> String {
        if(pets.count>0) {
            let pet : AnimalType = pets[0];
            let name = pet.name ?? "someone"
            return "I'm playing with \(name). \(pet.sound())"
        } else {
            return "No animals"
        }
    }
}

class AnimalFactory {
    let factoryMethod : () -> AnimalType

    init(factoryMethod: () -> AnimalType) {
        self.factoryMethod = factoryMethod
    }
}

// Create a container and register service and component pairs.
let container = Container()
container.register(AnimalType.self) { _ in Cat(name: "Mimi") }
container.register(PersonType.self) { r in PetOwner(petFactory: r.resolve(AnimalFactory.self)!) }

container.register(AnimalFactory.self){r in AnimalFactory(factoryMethod:{ () -> AnimalType in r.resolve(AnimalType.self)!}) }

// The person is resolved to a PetOwner with a Cat.
let person = container.resolve(PersonType.self)!

person.createAnotherAnimal()

print(person.play())
```

Comment: Just be aware the you're trying to resolve the AnimalFactory before registering it.